# How can I prepare class for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my class:

```
.yt-card.yt-uix-expander .yt-uix-button-expander, .yt-card .yt-uix-expander .yt-uix-button-expander
```

Is there any way to write it nice in:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "write it nice"? And that's not a class (not even close)

Comment: change your class to a single word lol and also you have multiple classes in your code above

Comment: Not just multiple classes, it's worse than that - it's a multi-part selector, each part of which names either elements with multiple classes, or multiple elements. The question makes no sense.

Comment: I know, so I am asking. In ("..."); i can't have dots but .yt-card.yt-uix-expander... so what can I do with it?

Comment: Or maybe easier. How to put this: .yt-card.yt-uix-expander .yt-uix-button-expander into document.getElementsByClassName?

Comment: That were not multiple classes - youtube (that are classes of youtube - dont blame me) makes them especially for IE.

Answer (score 2):

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".yt-card.yt-uix-expander .yt-uix-button-expander, .yt-card .yt-uix-expander .yt-uix-button-expander");
```